# how to display directive scoped objects in the view in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How do I display the `$scope.attributes` array in my html?

for example how would I display the JSON collection after pushing the buttons multiple times

`[{'row'},{'tout'},{'row'}]`..etc

Is there a better way to do this like return the directive objects to the parent controller?  even if this isnt the proper way how would you do this.. lol?

### [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/89AYX/56/)

**html**

```
  <div ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
        <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

            <h4>directive to directive communication</h4>
            <btn row></btn>
            <btn tout></btn>
            {{btn.attributes | json}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
    angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
        .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
           $scope.attributes = [];
           $scope.alertMessage = function(message) {
                alert(message); 
            }
           $scope.applyAlert = function() {
                alert('asdlfkjsadlfkj'); 
           }
        })
        .directive('btn', function() {
          return {
            restrict: 'E',
              scope: {},
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.attributes = []

                this.addRow = function() {
                 $scope.attributes.push('row')   
                }
                this.addTout = function() {
                 $scope.attributes.push('tout')   
                }
            },
              link: function(scope, element) {
                  element.bind('click', function(){
                      console.log(scope.attributes);
                  })   
              }

          };
        })
      .directive('row', function() {
          return{
              restrict: 'A',
              require: 'btn',
              template: '<button>add Row</button>',
              link: function(scope, element, attrs, btnCtrl) {
                  btnCtrl.addRow();
              }
          };
      })
      .directive('tout', function() {
          return{
              restrict: 'A',
              require: 'btn',
              template: '<button>add tout</button>',
              link: function(scope, element, attrs, btnCtrl) {
                  btnCtrl.addTout();
              }
          };
      })
```

Comment: What would you like rendered in place of `{{btn.attributes}}`?

Comment: Yes that would be perfect

Comment: No, I meant can you give an example of what information you would want rendered in place of `{{btn.attributes}}`.  I'm having a hard time understanding what your expectation is since there are 2 `btn` directives.

Comment: Ahh sorry,  on click of either button I would like it to push the strings [{row}, {tout}, {row}...etc] I think {{btn.attributes | json }}

Comment: Does that make more sense? I've also updated the question to reflect the comments concerns better?

Comment: Yes, I think I get it now. I'm thinking about what the best approach would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy2Qv/).

Since you are declaring `btn` as isolated scope (`scope: {}`) you cannot affect the scope of the controller (without requiring it).

In this HTML:

```
<div ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

        <h4>directive to directive communication</h4>
        <btn row></btn>
        <btn tout></btn>
        {{btn.attributes | json}}
    </div>
</div>
```

`btn.attributes` is in the scope of the controller.  It is *not* in the scope of `btn`.  Scopes in Angular are always *hung* off of the DOM element on which they are required.

Also, neither the `btn` attribute or the controller declare a scoped property named `btn.attributes`.  They both declare just `attributes`.

So, if we use this HTML:

```
<div ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <hr /> <hr /> <hr />
        <h4>directive to directive communication</h4>
        <btn row></btn>
        <btn tout></btn>
        {{attributes}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And take off the isolated scope, you start to get the result you are after. So, one way to accomplish this would be to not make `btn` isolated scope:

```
.directive('btn', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope) {

            this.addRow = function() {
             $scope.attributes.push('row')   
            }
            this.addTout = function() {
             $scope.attributes.push('tout')   
            }
        },
          link: function(scope, element) {
              element.bind('click', function(){
                  console.log(scope.attributes);
              })   
          }

      };
    })
```

Comment: I probably gotta go back to the drawing board but I would like that on click it pushes a new row or tout object on the attributes array.

Comment: You could, then, fire an event that is caught, but that also has drawbacks.

Comment: You should be pushing an array item, and then use `ng-repeat` to render each `btn`.